# How can I target a random child element on each loop of anime.js?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm trying to target a random element on each loop of a keyframed anime.js animation.

Looking at the [documentation](https://animejs.com/documentation/#loopBeginLoopComplete), I can see that there is a `loopComplete` callback function.  So, I created a function to assign a random child element to the variable `random_target`.

While I can see in the console log that the value of `random_target` is changing, the anime.js loop continues to target the first-generated `random_target`.

How can I ensure that the animation re-targets on loop completion?

```js
var pulseTargets = document.querySelector(".pulse-parent").children;
var random_target = null;

function getRandomTarget() {
  random_target = pulseTargets[Math.floor(Math.random() * pulseTargets.length)];
}

getRandomTarget();
console.log(random_target);
anime({
  targets: random_target,
  keyframes: [{
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    opacity: 0.3
  }, {
    opacity: 1
  }],
  duration: 3000,
  loop: true,
  loopComplete: function(anim) {
    getRandomTarget();
    console.log(random_target)
  }
});
```

```css
.even\:font-light> :nth-child(even) {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.odd\:font-black> :nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container col-span-full mx-auto h-auto relative mt-32 pb-16">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3">
      <div class="pulse-parent block font-sans odd:font-black tracking-widest even:font-light text-amber-400 col-span-1 h-[6em] overflow-hidden -mt-4 text-justify" style="text-justify: inter-character">
        <span>CHILD1</span> <span>CHILD2</span> <span>CHILD3</span> <span>CHILD4</span> <span>CHILD5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[codepen here if snippet is not working](https://codepen.io/BathtubJoe/pen/yLPPGLW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the `anim` object supplied to the callback function, I was able to figure this out.  I needed to update a few targets on the animation object, because once initialized the animation doesn't look for an updated target value.

```js
    var pulseTargets = document.querySelector('.pulse-parent').children
    var random_target = null
    function getRandomTarget() {
        random_target =  pulseTargets[Math.floor(Math.random() * pulseTargets.length)]
    }

    getRandomTarget()
    console.log(random_target)
    anime({
        targets: random_target,
        keyframes: [
            {opacity: 1},
            {opacity: 0.3},
            {opacity: 1}
        ],
        duration: 3000,
        loop: true,
        loopComplete: function (anim) {
            getRandomTarget();
            anim.targets = random_target;
            anim.animatables[0].target = random_target;
            anim.animations[0].animatable.target = random_target;
        }
    })
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works for me.